# Spring data jpa queries returns wrong information

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a "simple" application where I store user data on a Mysql db and look at them using an API.

I'm using Spring boot and I'm struggling with Spring Data JPA. I've switched from javaEE to spring a few times ago and i have to admit that this abstraction is kinda weird to absorb. I've read a lot about it and my issue concerns the boolean information retrieval.

I'll explain more in details (but you'll see this case is quite classic):
I have an entity with some properties (uuid / phone_number / call_date) and my db is configured through the application.properties file.

Before adding a new object to my db i want to make sure that it is not already existing. To keep it simple, I want in a first time to check the phone number only.
To do so I'm using a repository :

```
public interface ProviderCallDetailRepository extends CrudRepository<ProviderCallDetail, String> {

    @Query("select count(e)>0 from ProviderCallDetail e where e.phoneNumber = :phone")
    boolean existsByPhoneNumber(@Param("phone")String phoneNumber);

    @Query("SELECT p FROM ProviderCallDetail p WHERE p.phoneNumber LIKE ?1")
    List<ProviderCallDetail> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);
}
```

I'm calling this method in my service :

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ProviderCallDetailDao {

    @Autowired
    private ProviderCallDetailRepository repository;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public boolean checkIfExists(ProviderCallDetail providerCallDetailToCheck) {
        if (repository.existsByPhoneNumber(providerCallDetailToCheck.getPhoneNumber()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep a look on my sql db and keep checking it by hand, everytime I insert data, even if the phone number is already persisted it returns false.
I've tried the findByPhoneNumber and everytime i got a list of 0 items.

Whereas, when i execute the equivalent sql query on my db, i got the right number of entries.

I don't know what I should take a look at right now, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT : And the ProviderCallDetail

```
@Entity
public class ProviderCallDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private UUID uuid;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private LocalDate callDate;

    public ProviderCallDetail(){
        super();
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    public ProviderCallDetail(String phoneNumber, LocalDate callDate) {
        super();
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.callDate = callDate;
    }

    public ProviderCallDetail(UUID uuid, String phoneNumber, LocalDate callDate) {
        super();
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.callDate = callDate;
    }

    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber.substring(0, phoneNumber.length()-2);
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public LocalDate getCallDate() {
        return callDate;
    }

    public void setCallDate(LocalDate callDate) {
        this.callDate = callDate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Done. Just deleted the unused properties to have something clearer.

Comment: Is there a reason you are returning a substring of phoneNumber instead of the whole phoneNumber? (in  `getPhoneNumber()`)

Comment: Well.. thanks you just answered my question... if i only return a substring i can't check if the phone number exists in the database >_<

And it's made like this for security reasons, to avoid users to access it.

Comment: Do you execute a test or is when you run the application?